# Run method only when it is called (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

**What is the problem?**

The problem I am encountering is that when I navigate through different diagrams (only when I navigate), the diagrams gets slower and slower.. There is a memory leak and I can't figure out how to solve the problem, so I thought of showing you guys the JQuery event code that is responsible for displaying the diagram, and also the content for one diagram out of 5.

What I really want, is that the user can navigate freely without any performance slowing down, please I need help with this, I have been working on this code for 6 days now, an I now the problem can be solved!!

**What I am trying to achieve?**

I want the user to have the opportunity to navigate through the five diagrams freely, keep in mind that the user can only view one diagram at a time. To the left there is a list where the user must click in order to view the diagram, and to the right is where the diagram is going to be displayed. (Every diagram is dynamic).

**Diagram1.js:** I have 4 other diagrams that have the same code structure but different values.

```
(function (){

        var dps1 = []; 

        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("table1",
        { 
          title:{
            text: "This is Diagram 1"  
          },      
          data: [
          {        
            type: "spline",
            name: "Temp Cylinder 1",
            dataPoints: dps1
          }
        });

        var xVal = 0;
        var yVal = 100;  
        var updateInterval = 50; 
        var dataLength = 50; 

    var updateChart = function (count) {
            count = count || 1;
            // count is number of times loop runs to generate random dataPoints.
            for (var j = 0; j < count; j++) {
                yVal = yVal +  Math.round(5 + Math.random() *(-5-5));  
                dps1.push({
                    x: xVal,
                    y: yVal       
                });
                xVal++;
            };  
            if (dps1.length > dataLength )
            {
                dps1.shift();             
            }    
            chart.render();     
        };

        // generates first set of dataPoints
        updateChart(dataLength); 
        // update chart after specified time. 
        setInterval(function(){updateChart()}, updateInterval); 
}());
```

**list.JS:** is responsible for displaying the diagram after each click. `var pres_row` without this, when the user clicks on the same row multiple times, the diagram slows down..

```
    var pres_row = 0; // Only one click

    $('[data-row]').on('click', function() {
         var row = $(this).attr('data-row');
         $('.active').removeClass('active');
         $('#table' + row).addClass('active'); 

             if(row == 1 && pres_row != 1){
                pres_row = 1
                $.getScript("diagram1.js");
             } else if (row == 2 && pres_row != 2) {
                pres_row = 2;
                $.getScript("diagram2.js"); 
             } else if (row == 3 && pres_row != 3) {
                pres_row = 3;
                $.getScript("diagram3.js"); 
             } else if (row == 4 && pres_row != 4) {
                pres_row = 4;
                $.getScript("diagram4.js");
             }else if (row == 5 && pres_row != 5) {
                pres_row = 5;
                $.getScript("diagram5.js");
             }
```

Comment: You keep loading the script files over and over again, adding each one to your page numerous times.

Comment: @Nit, know, how could I prevent this. I want it to only load when the user loads it.

Comment: @MartinE.Zulliger, but I want the user to be able to view the diagram until he decides to view another one. Will setTimeout be like a timer of how long he can view the diagram and stop it, or I am thinking wrong?

Answer (score 1):

As @Nit said, you are loading your script files again and again into the page leaving numerous intervals running without cleaning them up.

You need to employ some strategy where you a) load diagramX.js only if it is not already loaded previously and b) have a way to clear any intervals that are already in motion before starting one for the current one.

Example: You can define the functions in each diagram1.js like:

```
// global interval handle
var diagramInterval1 = false;

// make it named, so you can check if it is already loaded
function diagram1() {
    ...
    diagramInterval1 = setInterval(updateChart, updateInterval); 
}
```

And in list.js, for loading:

```
if(row !== pres_row){

    // clear the currently running interval if any
    if('diagramInterval' + pres_row in window) {
        clearInterval(window['diagramInterval' + pres_row]);
    }

    pres_row = row;

    // load only if not loaded
    if('diagram' + pres_row in window) {
        window['diagram' + pres_row]();
    }
    else {
        $.getScript("diagram" + pres_row + ".js", function() {
            window['diagram' + pres_row]();
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but could you please check my latest post here, does it look correct sir?

Comment: It works!!! So many days of work, finally everything works exactly as I want. You have saved our grade in this bachelor project sir! Now performance has increased over 500 % for our application.

Answer (score 0):

@techfoobar, did you mean like this inside diagram1.js

```
(function (){

        var dps1 = []; 

        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("table1",
        { 
          title:{
            text: "This is Diagram 1"  
          },      
          data: [
          {        
            type: "spline",
            name: "Temp Cylinder 1",
            dataPoints: dps1
          }
        });

        var xVal = 0;
        var yVal = 100;  
        var updateInterval = 50; 
        var dataLength = 50; 

    var updateChart = function (count) {
            count = count || 1;
            // count is number of times loop runs to generate random dataPoints.
            for (var j = 0; j < count; j++) {
                yVal = yVal +  Math.round(5 + Math.random() *(-5-5));  
                dps1.push({
                    x: xVal,
                    y: yVal       
                });
                xVal++;
            };  
            if (dps1.length > dataLength )
            {
                dps1.shift();             
            }    
            chart.render();     
        };

// global interval handle
var diagramInterval1 = false;

// make it named, so you can check if it is already loaded
function diagram1() {
    ...
    diagramInterval1 = setInterval(updateChart, updateInterval); 
} 
}());
```